# How to check if user push up (scroll top < 0 ) in iPhone

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, detection

Anywhy can i **detect** when user **push up** when scroll top less than 0 ? *(Like facebook app reload)*

**This is my code idea so far :**

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    scrollTop = hasOffset ? window.pageYOffset : docBody.scrollTop;
    detect_pushUp(scrollTop);
};

var push_up_check = true;
function detect_pushUp(scrollPosition) {
   if(scrollPosition === 0 && !push_up_check) {
     push_up_check = true;
   } else if(scrollPosition === 0 && push_up_check) {
     location.reload(true);
   } else {
     push_up_check = false;
   }
}
```

This is working ok, But any better idea? to detect something like this?

Comment: If it's working ok, then why do u need a better idea?

Comment: this is a perfect code ? @chris97ong